# use Hokuyo LIDAR with ethernet in ROS

Tags: lidar, laser, turtlebot, hokuyo, ethernet

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!
I got a Hokuyo UTM-30LX-EW which I would like to use with my Turtlebot. The sensor has a power and an ethernet connector. I connected the power to the turtlebot, it seems to be working. I connected the ethernet cable to the wifi router. I can ping the sensors IP from the turtlebot, it seems to be up and running.

I then installed the ros_groovy_laser_drivers package. Then I wanted to try:

```
roslaunch hokuyo_node hokuyo_test.launch
```

I get the following warning and error:

```
[ WARN] [1363863375.680619490]: The use_rep_117 parameter has not been specified and has been automatically set to true.  This parameter will be removed in Hydromedusa.  Please see: http://ros.org/wiki/rep_117/migration
[ERROR] [1363863375.690137879]: Exception thrown while opening Hokuyo. Failed to open port: /dev/ttyACM0. No such file or directory (errno = 2). The requested port does not exist. Is the hokuyo connected? Was the port name misspelled? (in hokuyo::laser::open) You may find further details at http://www.ros.org/wiki/hokuyo_node/Troubleshooting
```

I wasn't very surprised, since I haven't set the ip of the sensor neither in ROS nor in Ubuntu, so probably that's why I don't have the missing port. I don't know how to set this up. The pages regarding the ros hokuyo node don't mention any IP or ethernet related topics.
However, I found a page with the iri_hokuyo driver (http://mediabox.grasp.upenn.edu/roswiki/doc/api/iri_hokuyo_laser/html/), which referst to ethernet and USB ports. Unfortunately, I can't find the iri_hokuyo driver in the ubuntu/ros repositories.

Could someone tell me how should I set up the Hokuyo sensor?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/58822/use-hokuyo-lidar-with-ethernet-in-ros/) by [ZoltanS](https://answers.ros.org/users/4436/zoltans/) on ROS Answers with karma: 248 on 2013-03-21

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [anonymous8676](https://answers.ros.org/users/8676/anonymous8676/) on 2014-07-31**:
Are you aware of any differences (pros/conns) of using an ethernet interface over the usb interface?
I am currently evaluating Hokuyo sensors for my application and would like to know if there is any advantage in either interface.
Apologies for commenting on an old topic.
Regards,
Chris.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There's an actively maintained wrapper for urgwidget here:
https://github.com/ros-drivers/urg_node

Eventually, this may replace hokuyo_node as the recommended hokuyo driver - even for PR2.

To install:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-groovy-urg-node
```

To run (for ethernet):

```
rosrun urg_node urg_node _ip_address:="192.168.0.10"
```

---

Originally posted by [Chad Rockey](https://answers.ros.org/users/29/chad-rockey/) with karma: 4541 on 2013-03-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ZoltanS](https://answers.ros.org/users/4436/zoltans/) on 2013-03-28**:
Thanks Chad! It is working!

**Comment by [Airuno2L](https://answers.ros.org/users/458/airuno2l/) on 2013-04-23**:
Are there any options for Fuerte? I need to use an ethernet UTM-30LX-EW and it would be convient if it worked with Fuerte.

**Comment by [Chad Rockey](https://answers.ros.org/users/29/chad-rockey/) on 2013-04-23**:
I'm not aware of any options for Fuerte.  You could make a fork and convert it back to rosbuild.  :P

**Comment by [Airuno2L](https://answers.ros.org/users/458/airuno2l/) on 2013-04-23**:
Thanks for the reply. I ended up using this http://devel.iri.upc.edu/docs/labrobotica/hokuyo_laser_2d/index.html But it was quite involved

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As of 3/21/2013 there is no support for the Multiecho/Ethernet version of the Hokuyo in the hokuyo_node.  It is expected to be added in the next version of ROS, which would be Hydro.  Here is the issue tracker in GIT: https://github.com/ros-drivers/hokuyo_node/issues/2

They would probably be able to give you a better answer of their status, if you contact them directly.

---

Originally posted by [Raptor](https://answers.ros.org/users/3237/raptor/) with karma: 377 on 2013-03-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ZoltanS](https://answers.ros.org/users/4436/zoltans/) on 2013-03-21**:
Thank you Raptor!

**Comment by [Raptor](https://answers.ros.org/users/3237/raptor/) on 2013-03-26**:
This was just posted also: http://ros-users.122217.n3.nabble.com/Hokuyo-UTM-30LX-EW-td4019843.html